# System.InvalidOperationException при попытке сохранить данные

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
 if (creditRent.mast_be_pay_credit >= payCount)
                        { 
                            PaymenResultEntity pre = new PaymenResultEntity();
                            creditRent.mast_be_pay_credit -= payCount;
                            creditRent.how_much_to_pay_Credit += payCount;
                            PaymenResult pr = new PaymenResult(0, "Dont error");
                            pre.error_cod = pr.errorCode;
                            pre.error_description = pr.errorDescrip;
                            pre.date_of_rent = DateTime.Now;
                            pre.payment_ID = paymentId;
                            sde.SaveChanges();
                        }
```

Доброго времени суток!
Вот у меня такой код но при попытке `sde.SaveChanges();`  возникает исключение с таким сообщением. 
Помогите решить эту проблему.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: The property 'how_much_to_pay_Credit' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в таблице не задан первичный ключ. Или вы его таким выставили?
Если не задан первичный ключ, то EF берет ненулевые столбцы и на основе их определяет первичный ключ, а сама сущность становится доступной для чтения.
Поэтому задайте таблице первичный ключ и проблема уйдет.